# Creating an SKTextureAtlas from a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, sktextureatlas

If an iOS project has a dictionary of UIImages, how can an SKTextureAtlas be properly created from the dictionary images at runtime?  I haven't been able to accomplish this goal, though Apple's SKTextureAtlas class reference suggests the following when declaring the atlas: convenience init!(dictionary properties: [NSObject : AnyObject]).

For example, how can the following code be completed or reworked to create an SKTextureAtlas from the UIImages in tempDictionary?

```
var strawberryDrawing:UIImage = UIImage(named: "strawberry")!
var bananaDrawing:UIImage = UIImage(named: "banana")!

var tempDictionary:[String:UIImage] = ["First Fruit":strawberryDrawing, "Second Fruit":bananaDrawing]

var atlasOfFruitDrawings:SKTextureAtlas = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let strawberryDrawing = UIImage(named: "strawberry")!
let bananaDrawing = UIImage(named: "banana")!
let tempDictionary: [NSObject:AnyObject] = ["First Fruit":strawberryDrawing, "Second Fruit":bananaDrawing]
let atlasOfFruitDrawings = SKTextureAtlas(dictionary: tempDictionary)
```